# Google Sheets IMPORTXML returns nothing from straightforward query

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to automate collection of Formula 1 results data using Google Sheets and IMPORTXML. There is a developer site that makes collection simple by pre-formatting into a table.

Example of results site, used to pull XML table from: http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results

When inspecting the site, the results table is tagged as such:

```
<tr>
<th>Pos</th>
<th>No</th>
<th>Driver</th>
<th>Constructor</th>
<th>Laps</th>
<th>Grid</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>Charles Leclerc</td>
<td>Ferrari</td>
<td>71</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1:24:24.312</td>
<td>Finished</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>
[....continues on with one table row per driver for 20 rows]
```

I simply want to pull the results into Google Sheets. My formula is:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results","//tr")
```

The error I get is "Imported content is empty."

I'm able to use this formula on other sites, for instance:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_farming","//tr")
```

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34620923/15019380

Comment: @MikeSteelson one follow-up after working with this solution - is there no way to just pull the whole table, since it doesn’t appear to be a named local element?

Comment: You see the table in the navigator, that is ok. BUT, the source doesn't contain any <table> tag. Click right on the navigator and check the code source of the page, you will see what I put as a screenshot herefater https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCNz6.png. What you can only choose is one of the tag as a local-name since at the beginning you have an `xmlns` that is a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the table formatting is loaded using javascript - which can't be handled by `IMPORTXML()`. Fortunatley, the page loads its actual data, in xml format, without using javascript. So, for example,

```
=IMPORTXML("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results","//*[local-name()='Driver']")
```

will output

```
16  Charles Leclerc 1997-10-16  Monegasque
33  Max Verstappen  1997-09-30  Dutch
44  Lewis   Hamilton    1985-01-07  British
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is an xml formated file as you can see in the source

[image]

This site uses a [namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/), so you will have to use local-name

```
=importxml(A1,"//*[local-name() ='Driver']")
```

[image]